# Hector slam incremental mapping

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, hector, 2d-mapping, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to have hector slam loaded with a pre-saved map , but NOT for localization only (so can't go to AMCL) , it is for performing mapping and update the saved map with the new info found in the world that weren't in the saved map (the world changed) .

To be specific : suppose a robot scanned the map of an entire floor with hector slam and saved the map successfully . Now next time the robot will use the saved map , BUT the floor itself changed a little bit (positions of obstacles changed, new obstacles or new free areas rise) so I want  be aware and map those to the saved map , sort of logical OR operator between the saved map and hector's incremental findings.

If I tried just publish the saved map to the hector's map topic , hector will overwrite it with its own map , so maybe if there's a way to just make hector take the last msg from the map topic , (logical or ) to add the new updates , and then publish it .

This will not make it a closed loop in the sense that it closed the loop to improve performance in any way , its just publishing updates on the saved thing instead of publishing a new thing

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/349724/hector-slam-incremental-mapping/) by [amhadR](https://answers.ros.org/users/53173/amhadr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can look in to Jin-W-FS's Pull Request at https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_slam/pull/45

I am also currently trying to implement the features that you have mentioned.

---

Originally posted by [jjbecomespheh](https://answers.ros.org/users/55607/jjbecomespheh/) with karma: 18 on 2020-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [amhadR](https://answers.ros.org/users/53173/amhadr/) on 2020-08-04**:
great !
I'll mark this as an answer since I didn't find more useful resources.

It seems that the PR works well when the robot starts from the same initial pose of the saved map , but I still have to try myself , did you try it and can confirm?